# How to pass data to detail view after being selected in a table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that has data populated from an NSMutableArray called userList. When specific user is selected, it goes to a detail view, and updates the title in the NavBar, but it wont pass the data to update a UILabel in the UIView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

//Attempt at a singleton to pass the data
DetailView *details = [[DetailView alloc] init];
details.userNameLbl = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


DetailView *detailVC = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

//This line doesn't pass the data
detailVC.userNameLbl.text = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//This line does update the title in the NavBar
detailVC.navigationItem.title = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

[details release];
[detailVC release];

}
```

Should I be trying to push the data from the table view to the detail view, or have the detail view try to pull the data from the table view?

DetailView.h has the following line that is in fact hooked up in IB.

```
IBOutlet UILabel *userNameLbl
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `userNamelbl` isn't instantiated until the view is loaded from the nib file. This doesn't happen immediately at initialisation, but will have happened by the time `viewDidLoad` is called.

So, you should to declare a property in DetailView to store your title, and then assign that value to `userNamelbl.text` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

For example, in your table viewController:

```
DetailView *detailVC = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
detailVC.userName = [userList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

and in your detail viewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.userNameLbl.text = self.userName;
}
```

The viewController's navigationItem property is created when the viewController is initialised, hence you can assign to the `navigationItem.title` immediately.

---

*Swift code*

```
let detailVC = DetailView(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
detailVC.userName = userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSString
```

and

```
class DetailView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userNameLbl: UILabel
    var userName:NSString?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.userNameLbl.text = self.userName
    }    
}
```

Comment: Also, you can consider having a `User` class and passing an instance of it to your view.  Then your view can initialize any parts of itself that are specific to the user.  It may even help to make this `User` class be a Core Data entity type.

Comment: Doing this has caused a warning for an NSString and UILabel mismatch on types - is there a way to implement your solution and avoid this?

Comment: I assumed that userList is an array of NSStrings. If the userName property is also be an NSString, you shouldn't get a mismatch

Answer (score 4):

Are you mixing `UIViews` and `UIViewControllers`? You should have a `DetailViewController` class that inherits from `UIViewController` or some sublcass (like `UITableViewController`); it will have `DetailViewController.m` and `DetailViewController.h` files to declare and define your class. It should have a corresponding nib that defines the `UIView` that the `UIViewController` loads; it will have a `DetailView.xib` file.

You can't assign the value to the `UILabel` directly because `UIView` hasn't been loaded at the time you need to assign the user name value.

In order to do what you want, you should declare a public property (`userName`) to "push" the value onto the detail view controller from the master controller. Once the detail view is loaded, it can assign the value from the property to the label and nav bar.

In your master view controller (`UITableViewController`):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

    detailVC.userName = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

    [detailVC release];
}
```

In your detail view controller:

DetailViewController.h

```
@property (retain) NSString* userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *userNameLbl;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
@synthesize userName;
@synthesize userNameLbl;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.userNameLbl.text = self.userName;
    self.navigationItem.title = self.userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your `DetailView` requires the data from your selected row to function?

If so, I'd say the 'correct' approach would be to create a custom `init` method that passed in the data you required. For example:

```
[[DetailView alloc] initWithTitle:(NSString *)title text:(NSString *)text]
```

There's nothing inherently wrong with your approach, but passing the data the view controller requires at its creation is architecturally better (in my opinion, I'm sure someone will disagree!). For example, think of a table view controller - you pass in the table view style in the `init` method, you don't set it later on. Same for a `UIImageView` - you have an `initWithImage` method that lets you set the image at creation.

Comment: Conceptually, I definitely agree with your approach, but I am gonna need a little more help(im a noob) on the implementation.  My understanding is that the above line would go inside of my didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in the TableView, and then(this is where I get fuzzy) the actual implementation of the initWithTitle:text: method be in the DetailView. Right?

Comment: +1 for this approach. I would recommend this over the other approaches mentioned simply because of its simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @lxt I would love to see more on this solution, but I had to give the credit to AshleyMills because that is the solution I went with in my app. Thanks Everyone!