# Error when passing data between views

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, segue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass data to detail view after being selected in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562258/how-to-pass-data-to-detail-view-after-being-selected-in-a-table-view)

I'm using a plist (array of dictionaries) to populate a tableview. Now, when a cell i pressed, I want to pass the reprecented dictionary to the detail view with a segue. It's working properly to fill the tableview, but how do I send the same value to the detail view? This is my try:

```
#import "WinesViewController.h"
#import "WineObject.h"
#import "WineCell.h"
#import "WinesDetailViewController.h"

@interface WinesViewController ()

@end

@implementation WinesViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    wine = [[WineObject alloc] initWithLibraryName:@"Wine"];
    self.title = @"Vinene";
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [wine libraryCount];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"wineCell";

    WineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...


    cell.nameLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.districtLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"District"];
    cell.countryLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Country"];
    cell.bottleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];
    cell.flagImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Flag"]];
    cell.fyldeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Fylde"]];
    cell.friskhetImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Friskhet"]];
    cell.garvesyreImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Garvesyre"]];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        WinesDetailViewController *winesdetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        //Here comes the error line:
        winesdetailViewController.winedetailName = [wine objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    }
}
```

I get one error for:

```
winesdetailViewController.winedetailName = [wine objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

Use of undeclaired identifier: indexPath. did you mean NSIndexPath? I think I've missed something important here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `indexPath.row` (which doesn't exist in this function like it does in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function where it is passed as an argument) use `selectedRowIndex` like this:

```
 winesdetailViewController.winedetailName = [wine objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

Or, even better yet, change your detail view controller to just accept the whole dictionary, pass the dictionary, and let it set its' own values:

```
 winesdetailViewController.winedetail = [wine objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, there is no variable `indexPath` defined there. However, just a couple lines above that line you define `selectedRowIndex` which probably has the value that you're after.